# Cannot download from AWS S3: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

So I'm hosting an web app on EC2 which let users upload/download photos from S3. EC2 and S3 are in the same region.

**Credentials**: Following the official docs, credentials should be automatically supplied by the IAM role(with `s3fullAccess` permission) I created and associated to EC2.

**Problem**: User (from browser) can't download photos, but can successfully upload them. Download link was generated by `aws-sdk`'s `getSignedUrl()` method.

**Error Message**:

> InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

Firstly, `access key` seems correct as users can successfully upload stuffs.

My guess is that, since the user clicks link in the browser to download, there's no interaction between EC2 and S3, thus IAM role is not used when downloading. But isn't the `signedDownloadUrl` generated with EC2 credentials? And there's access key pairs supplied altogether in the query string. So my guess might be wrong..

Any suggestion/idea is appreciated.

**Edit**

I didn't create an IAM user, only have an IAM role. Don't know if this matters.

Comment: Have you tried downloading from a direct link to your S3 bucket? ex.`http://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/BUCKET/PATH/TO/IMAGE.jpeg` or `http://BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/PATH/TO/IMAGE.jpeg`. If you get the same error message, then check the privileges of your bucket and maybe CORS but that depends if your EC2 and S3 have different domains.

Comment: @zer00ne I can't, says access denied. There's a lock icon before the link

Comment: @zer00ne Error message are different. 'invalid access key id' from web app, and 'access denied' from s3 management console. EC2 and S3 in the same region as well.

Comment: Try pasting the S3 url directly into a browser's address bar

Comment: The `InvalidAccessKeyId` error... does that access-key-id start with `AKIA...` or `ASIA...`?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot It started with `ASIA`. Here's an complete url with query string: `http://bappo-bucket.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/FILE.1bee6f70-d954-11e6-9d7c-73c8c5ab192b.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAJYV3S4JASRHVIZTQ&Expires=1484401153&Signature=OkPXmGdINe3SnZccLZYzi8ZyVnc%3D` Do I have to create an IAM user and generate access key? Currently I only have IAM role and seems nowhere to generate access key for that role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ASIA...` *is* a temporary access key id from a set of temporary credentials for an IAM role.  (Role credentials are *always* temporary.) `AKIA...` is an IAM user.

The problem here is that the `x-amz-security-token` accompanying the credentials was not used in the signing process that generated the S3 signed URL, so it doesn't appear in the signed URL... but it needs to be there for this to work.

> If you are signing your request using temporary security credentials [...] you must include the corresponding security token in your request by adding the `x-amz-security-token` header.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#UsingTemporarySecurityCredentials

If you don't include `x-amz-security-token`, the system assumes it should look up the access-key-id in the IAM ussr database, and it won't be found there, which causes the *InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records* error.

Note that you can't simply add it to the already-generated URL.  It needs to be incorporated into the signing process.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. I forgot to include `x-amz-security-token` since I was using environment variables to authenticate before.